# Looking for a categoratisation of a poetic expression

Tags: poetic

I really like the poetic expression “Three peas in a pod” does anybody have a categoraisation for this type of expression so I can find more like it? This is really important to me I would really appreciate your help! Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 2):

The expression used in the question, "three peas in a pod", a *metaphor*.

From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/metaphor):

> : a figure of speech in which a word or phrase literally denoting one kind of object or idea is used in place of another to suggest a likeness or analogy between them (as in drowning in money)

In writing, a metaphor is a figurative expression that illustrates a concept. Here, "three peas in a pod" is used to express that the things being considered are so like each other that they might come from the same source.

Comment: Strictly speaking it's usually a ***simile***. As this [NGram shows](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=are+three+peas+in+a%2Clike+three+peas+in+a&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clike%20three%20peas%20in%20a%3B%2Cc0), *[they are] **like** three peas in a [pod]* is fairly common (where the word ***like*** makes it a simile, not a metaphor). But the "metaphor" phrasing isn't even common enough to chart at all.

Comment: The simile invokes a metaphor, though. The "three peas in a pod" portion of the simile is itself a metaphor, since the thing being compared rarely has anything at all in common with real peas in a real pea pod.

Comment: @R Mac: My favourite current offering from the BBC is [*Upstart Crow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart_Crow), where in last week's episode Will Shakespeare / David Mitchell was at great pains to ensure everyone agreed that some specific turn of phrase was a metaphor, not a simile. (Or the other way around, I don't actually remember that little detail! :)

Comment: Since when have the peas become "three"? Isn't it "two peas in a pod"?

Comment: https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/as-alike-as-two-peas-in-a-pod.html according to its origins, it's a simile...

Comment: According to its original, it's just a figure of speech. It doesn't get called a simile, a metaphor, or anything really until someone else comes along and tries to decide what it is.

Comment: Also, this makes me consider the difference between two similar common forms of this expression: "They are two peas in a pod," and, "They are like two peas in a pod." The former uses it as a metaphor, the latter as a simile.